# Label not inside border after map rotation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.4, maplex

[image: label]

Does anyone know why my label doesn't show normally within the label border when I apply a rotation to my map? It shows fine with zero rotation.

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using? Are you using the standard or Maplex labeling engine?

Comment: 10.4.1 Maplex label engine

Comment: I am guessing the anchor point on the text is different from the anchor point on the box, so they are rotating around different axes.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: I think the box's properties is probably set in a style set, but you can change the text alignment and see if it makes any difference. Go to your layers properties to the Labels tab, hit the Symbol button, the Edit Symbol. In the General tab make the Horizontal Alignment center and hit ok a few time and see if it is better/different. Also, I would turn Maplex off.. there's a reason they throw it in for free now.

Comment: Vertical and Horizontal Alignment options are grey'd out with baselline and left alignment checked.

Comment: I think if you center-align you might get a central anchor point..in order to get a left-aligned look you could just pad it with spaces... but check if changing from left to center makes any difference